# How to limit the number of searches per IP in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to limit number of searches one can do in my asp.net website. Also when a max number is exceeded,there has to be way to reset this count.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are 1001 approaches to this problem. One would be to just keep a track of queries using a database table with, at least, 2 fields: date and ip (and I would add the actual query as a third field and possibly the (logged in) user-id of the user doing the query). You can then easily get the count (per day/week/month/year/whatnot) per IP and possibly even by user (make sure you create the correct indices!) before executing a searchquery and then notify the user they're over their quota. As a bonus you get a history of searches (by date and IP, maybe even user) which you can use to analyse further (most searched keywords, most active user/ip, etc.).

You could also resort to other methods like keeping IP's + counter in memory (like a `Dictionary<ip, int>`), maybe even stored in something like memcached or just in the application scope, etc. etc. The approaches are countless and need to be suited to your requirements (which you didn't specify at all).

Resetting the count could be as simple as setting a counter to 0 (via the user-interface ofcourse), e.g. `MyQueryDictionary[userip] = 0` or as "complex" as 'upping a threshold for a specific IP in a database table' and everything in-between.